phpmyadmin does not work after upgrading ubuntu to 24.04
I upgraded my Ubuntu system from 20.04 lts to 22.04 lts and now when I try to access phpmyadmin it sends the error HTTP ERROR 500. The Apache service is working fine, as I have other websites that are working OK. My PHP version is 7.4. Any possible way to fix?

Please post the output of systemctl status apache2, a2query -m | grep '^php' and php --version

This may be of some help. This is the default software versions that come with Ubuntu 24.04. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS includes Python 3.12, Ruby 3.2, PHP 8.3

Cos agradezco la información que me proporcionas en un momento público la salida de comando systemctl status apache2, a2query -m | grep '^php'yphp --version

Gracias por la información David DE
